# how to call pause_physics service

Tags: ros, gazebo, physics, ros-groovy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

i cant seem to do:

```
pause_physics_client=rospy.ServiceProxy('/gazebo/pause_physics',PausePhysics)
```

there doesn't seem to be a PausePhysics.srv anywhere under gazebo_msgs/srv

I can see that the service is running in rosservice list, and I'm using groovy.

What should I be doing instead? All I want is a way to toggle physics inside my code.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/59049/how-to-call-pause_physics-service/) by [mugetsu](https://answers.ros.org/users/1134/mugetsu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 195 on 2013-03-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`gazebo/pause_physics` is an Empty service (no inputs or output arguments), so doesn't need its own service definition.  See this section from the wiki page:

```
~/pause_physics (std_srvs/Empty)
    Pause physics updates. 

~/unpause_physics (std_srvs/Empty)
    Resume physics updates.
```

Try this and see if it works:

```
from std_srvs.srv import Empty
pause_physics_client=rospy.ServiceProxy('/gazebo/pause_physics',Empty)
```

If you need it, `gazebo/unpause_physics` is also an Empty service.

---

Originally posted by [Jeremy Zoss](https://answers.ros.org/users/3925/jeremy-zoss/) with karma: 4976 on 2013-03-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1